# How can I force a decimal to be formatted with two digits?

Tags: ruby, format

I'm trying to figure out how I can format a number, like `29.9`, as `29.90`. I've tried this so far:

```
number = 29.90
#=> 29.9

number.to_s
#=> "29.9"

number.round(2).to_s
#=> "29.9"
```

What method should I use to get `"29.90"`?

Comment: Not duplicate because I don't want to set the precision. I want to fill with 0.

Comment: '%.02f' % p.round(2)

Comment: you are Welcome @B413

Comment: Hey, I've done my best to fix up the English in this question. Look it over and see if I messed anything up. (I assumed you meant just formatting it as a string, rather than printing it, because of your code example)

Comment: @B413 in case you're wondering why I've renamed the variable: [`p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p) is a method in Ruby that prints its arguments. And since you're question is related to formatting / output, a variable with the same name can be quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'%.02f' % number
#=> "29.90"
```

Thanks to Gourav Naik

Answer (score 0):

Is this working for you?

```
printf( "%.02f", 22.9 )
```

Comment: why the ```round(2)```?

Comment: @pascalbetz was a test with an other number :)